# How to uninstall VMs installed with ubuntu-vm-builder

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

How do I list (and uninstall) VMs installed with `ubuntu-vm-builder` but NOT with `virsh`?

### Details

---

Whilst following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/CreateGuests), I was keen to get started and typed in:

```
sudo ubuntu-vm-builder kvm precise
```

before seeing the note about how it is important to add this option:

```
--libvirt=qemu:///system
```

if I want to be able to manage it with `virsh`. Now it is installed, I have no idea how to list what I have installed or where it is. I want to undo what I've done (uninstall the VM) so that I can install it with that option so that I can manage it with virsh.

All the tutorials I found use Virsh so I don't know how to uninstall what I have installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in /media/Data/KVM (or the specified location if a location other than default was specified), find the VM you wish to delete and do `rm VMfilename`

Comment: I ran: `sudo find / -name "KVM" -type d | wc -l` but there are no KVM folders on my machine, is there anything else I can search for or did it somehow not install?

Comment: Then look for the name of the VM you created.

Comment: Aha, the `--dest` option appears to be the intuitively named option for what the "name of the VM" will be, as I didn't specify it will use default. According to the man page for ubuntu-vm-builder, the default is "ubuntu-vm-#{something about suite and arch}" so I did `sudo find / -name "ubuntu-vm*" -type d` and deduced that it must have not installed and failed quietly or something